# Difficulty constructing hierarchical JSON from Elasticsearch Data

Tags: elasticsearch, treeview

[image]

This is the Tree structure I am working on,
the data is being fetched from Elastic.

I want to implement search functionality, if user search for anything
i want to return the complete Json path of **searched object**.

**What I've tried**
I have created a method which takes ID and give me complete Json hierarchy
But the method is very **costly**

***Example***:Lets say I search for "D"

**Expected Output** :
[image]